# User Group permission for apache website

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, file-permissions, user-permissions

Apache is running with `www-data:www-data`

I added a user

```
sudo useradd -s /bin/false -d /var/www/dev -m dev
```

and added to www-data group

```
sudo usermod -G www-data --append dev

uid=1001(dev) gid=1001(dev) groups=1001(dev),33(www-data)
```

Now when a website running from `/var/www/dev`, it is getting permission denied error when trying to write something like logs,cache.
All files and folder at `/var/www/dev` is `dev:dev`. Not using Suexec.

But if I am changing group to `dev:www-data` it is working fine.

How I can get write permission for apache with `dev:dev` permission?

Answer (score 0):

If apache is running as 'www-data' user, then the 'www-data' user needs to be in the 'dev' group or the website files all need the www-data as the group owner.  Your 'dev' user is in www-data group, but it's not the user executing the commands.